# Silex (Symfony 3 components) all parameters configuration list

Tags: symfony, silex, symfony-security, symfony-components

I started learning silex framework (based on symfony). I write code like this

```
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
'security.firewalls' => [
    'admin' => [
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'form' => ['login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/check'],
        'users' => ['ROLE_ADMIN']
    ]
]
]);
```

There are many configuration options like pattern, form, users etc (example). Where I find all configuration options for every Provider (in documentation often there are few but not all). I searched in API but I didn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Silex uses Symfony components and each providers coming from his internal library loads different components.

So for documentation about security, I advise you to start looking there :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html